# Weird Line in Grass (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rendering

I have a weird line in the left of my grass texture I've looked far and wide, no solution works

Picture:
[image]

See that weird light green lines popping up near other grass? That's it too. Kinda hard to see on the grass right there, but the grass around it also has the lines The trees are black because my laptop is very slow and is still processing lighting I've tried:

Setting Wrap Mode to Clamp

Setting Filter Mode to Point

Made it 16 bit, which made the background a solid color

Turned off mipmapping, and played around with some of it's settings

and probably others i forget here, since i've been trying to fix this for so long' also, i tried this out on a different terrain and when there is no other detail meshes, there is no line, but if there is, there's a line also, that's the only grass texture and every other detail mesh is a 3D object and rendered as "Vertex Lit" instead of grass, so I don't know if those meshes can bleed into my grass texutre, like other posts have mentioned.

Tried just about every solution ive found on many pages of google, like the ones i listed above with playing around with the grass texture and the terrain. Nothing worked.

Other pictures of grass also had this bug

Original picture of grass as a png:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check the texture itself, it seems to follow the texture of the grass and looks as though the line is actually in the texture. In which case, use a photo editing tool like GIMP to remove it.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it
it didn't work. I'll add the picture of the grass in the post, but i really can't find a solution.
i doubt it's with the picture itself because it works on other terrains without other detail meshes